# Scrollbar issue in webkit on Mac OS X

Tags: html, css, macos, webkit

Both Chrome and Safari shows a weird behaviour on the scrollbars at a site I'm coding.

The scrollbar hides under :after and :before elements as shown below:

[image]

The styles that makes them hide under the block:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
margin-left: -2%;
display: block;
content: '';
width: 110%;
height: 60px;
margin-top: -30px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
transform: rotate(-2deg);
background: #fff;
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

Does anyone know why the scrollbar behaves like this?

Comment: Yes, I've seen CSS transformations do very weird things; leak out of iframes and such. And not just in Webkit! Would it help to put the whole thing in a container with `overflow:hidden`? (Of course that would mean you could never get a horizontal scrollbar.)

Comment: Kinda figured it was a bug afterall, guess i'll have to find a way to go around this until it's fixed.

Comment: @MrLister It's already set to overflow:hidden on a parent though.