# OS X WebView scrollbar redrawing/flickering/flashing issue

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, scrollbar

I'm having an issue with scrollbar of an `WebView` on OS X Yosemite. The `WebView` is setup in a XIB file, kept default settings. And then load the content with:

```
[self.webView.mainFrame loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

But when scrolling I see redrawing/flickering/flashing issue of the scrollbar: [example video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1934568/WebKit%20Scrollbar%20Issue.mp4). (This happens with all kind of content, I just recorded it with this random data)

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251674/scrollbar-issue-in-webkit-on-mac-os-x but I don't use any fancy css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was tricky to figure out, but here it goes: At first created a new project with just a `WebView` to see if I could reproduce it. I wasn't able to reproduce it there.

I switched back to my project and replaced the troublesome xib with a fresh one just containing a `WebView`. Again I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Next up was the more time consuming task of recreating the complete UI in a fresh xib. The problem wasn't reproducible with this xib either. Issue solved!

But what triggered the problem? After staring at the `diff` of the two xibs for a while I noticed something:

```
<customView alphaValue="0.99999999999999989" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eEn-AF-z0I">
```

Interface Builder still showed in the `Appearance` section an `Alpha` of `1`. Only changing it to something else and back to `1` fixed the xib:

```
<customView translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eEn-AF-z0I">
```

I'm still not sure what changed this value to begin with, but at least this fixes my issue. Also it makes sense layer related property causes this redrawing issue.

Layer backed WebView's aren't supported. From the Leopard release notes:

> Most of the standard views and controls that AppKit and Mac OS X's other Cocoa frameworks provide are able to function in layer-backed mode in Leopard, with the exception of certain specialized views such as WebKit WebViews and Quartz Composer QCViews, whose use in layer-backed mode is not presently supported.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#Animation - Last paragraph of the "New View Animation Facilities, and Layer-Backed View Drawing" section