# WKWebview flickering - but not when using WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, wkwebview, macos-sierra

OK, so here's the issue I'm facing.

I have a window with a `WKWebView` in it. When the window is resized, the webview is to be resized.

The thing is when I'm trying to increase the window's size (or - far more noticeable - when maximizing the window) there is a flicker, with a white background, until the webview redraws itself.

Now, the weird thing is: when I'm using a `WebView` (yes, the supposedly "legacy" one), this works flawlessly.

What's going on? Is there any way to work with a `WKWebView` on MacOS without this flicker?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258074/os-x-webview-scrollbar-redrawing-flickering-flashing-issue